# JQuery binding onclick to parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My other question did not get a resolution, so I will try this with the changes I have made, it should be easier to understand and answer.

I am trying to bind an onclick to a dialog, that is working. However the onclick also needs to bind to the parent div that jQuery wraps around the dialog.

```
  open: function()
{
    $(this).bind('click', function(){
        $('#focusedPatient').val(thiskey);
    });
    $('div [aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-patient_22274"]').bind('click', function(){
        $('#focusedPatient').val(thiskey);
    });
}
```

The second bind is not working, i am guessing because of my syntax. After code execution it looks like

```
<div style="display: block; z-index: 1004; outline: 0px; height: auto;
width: auto; top: 141px; left: 50px;" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content
ui-corner-all ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-patient_22274">
  <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
    <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-patient_22274">
      <img src="imgs/omButtons/omIcon.png" border="0"> 
       IS0001_LG, Austin Smith, Date Created: NULL, Date Updated: NULL, 
       Created By: Michael</span>
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar-buttonpane" style="position: absolute; top: 50%;
    right: 0.3em; margin-top: -10px; height: 18px;">
       <a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"
       style="position: static; top: auto; right: auto; margin: 0px;">
         <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
       <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-maximize ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button" style="">
         <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-extlink">maximize</span></a>
       <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-restore ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button" 
       style="display: none;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin">restore</span></a>
       <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-minimize ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button" style="">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus">minimize</span></a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div onclick="$('#focusedPatient').val('22274')" id="patient_22274" 
   style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 113.375px; height: auto;" 
   class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content ui-dialog-normal" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
```

The first bind goes to the third div and works, i need to climb the dom tree to the container div which is the second onclick binding. Anyone know how to make that one work?

Comment: `$(this).parent().on('click', function() { ... });`

Comment: That's some nasty html. You should use [.parent() JQuery Function](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space in the selector. It should be

```
$('div[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-patient_22274"]')
```

However if it is the parent div you could just do

```
$(this).parent().bind('click', function() { ... })
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday and it did not work, trying it now it does so i must have had a typo or something. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes you might need to clear your browser's cache when making javascript changes to a page. If you use Chrome you can use Ctrl-Shift-R to reload a page ignoring cache.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.parent()` function:

```
   $(this).bind('click', function(){
        $('#focusedPatient').val(thiskey);
    });
   $(this).parent().bind('click', function(){
        $('#focusedPatient').val(thiskey);
    });
```

The reason your code isn't working is because `div [id=xyz]` is different from `div[id=xyz]`. The first means "any element with `id=xyz` within a `div`". The second means "any div with `id=xyz`". A space in jQuery means that you're talking about all children (recursively). So it *should* be `$('div[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-patient_22274"]')`

Comment: I tried with and without the space as i was not sure what the difference is, +1 for explaining the difference. Also the parent selector worked this time, i must have had a typo yesterday!.